# "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent."

Tags: powershell-3.0

Something has happened to my Windows Powershell, so whenever I open it there is a big long pause and then it says "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent." What is an authentication agent, and why is Powershell trying to open a connection to it?

Comment: Are you using git?

Comment: I have git installed, yes.

Comment: OK. The reason I asked is that googling for "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent" returns lots of results for git and/or ssh but nothing for powershell

Comment: Have you done something like in this link [http://haacked.com/archive/2011/12/19/get-git-for-windows.aspx/](Configure Git in PowerShell So You Don’t Have to Enter Your Password All the Damn Time)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SO] question [Connecting git to github on windows 7 without bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2328599)

Comment: But I'm not trying to do anything with ssh or github. I get this message when I am simply starting Powershell. The links provided don't provide answers to my problem, although maybe if I read them more careful I could start to deduce what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me:

Environment:
OS: Windows 10 Enterprise x64
Powershell running as administrator

1) Install ps-get: (type in powershell and enter

```
(new-object Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://psget.net/GetPsGet.ps1") | iex
```

2) Then:

```
Install-Module Posh-Git
```

3) Start powershell as admin in Bsldevutilities

3.1) Type

`ssh-agent`

3.2) type

```
ssh-add c:\users\yourname\.ssh\id_rsa
```